# inputText Syntax Error - missing ')'

Tags: visualforce, formula

I have an apex:inputText and I'm trying to set the initial value which the user can edit.  It's a simple IF formula but it keeps giving me the error:

> Syntax error.  Missing ')'

Here's the line (when I remove it the error goes away):

```
<apex:inputText id="daysToCount" style="width: 30px;" value="{!IF(prefs != null && prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c != null, TEXT(prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c), '30')}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Move your binary operators into a 'rendered' attribute to determine which type of input you want to show, than flip the variables accordingly:

```
<apex:inputText id="daysToCount" style="width: 30px;" value=" TEXT(prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c)}" rendered="{!IF(prefs != null && prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c != null)}"/>
<apex:inputText id="daysToCount" style="width: 30px;" value="30" rendered="{!IF(prefs != null && prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c == null)}"/>
```

Comment: Jordan: I think you have the parentheses around the first part wrong; wouldn't `IF(prefs!=null)` end the `IF` statement?

Comment: Your right, I reworked my answer.

Comment: I think maybe I'm getting confused here.  I don't want to bind the inputText variable on submit.  I just want to show either Recent_Interaction_Days__c or 30 depending on whether Recent_Interaction_Days__c has a value.  The user can then edit this value as they please.  I thought I could do this with IF[true/false condition: prefs != null && prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c != null][if true:TEXT(prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c)][if false:'30']

Comment: Oh my bad I thought you were working these binary operators for an 'rendered' attribute! Not 'value' - will try to rework my answer now.

Comment: If you have custom controller try the logic in controller itself.Thats the best practice

Comment: There is still a problem with the answer. The second inputText value argument is 30, but the value of inputText has to be a formula expression. The only way I can think to solve this is to assign the default value of 30 to Recent_Interaction_Days__c in the controller and use a single input text. It's moot but the rendered attributes could be cleaned up to use NOT(ISBLANK(prefs.Recent_Interaction_Days__c))

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up, I got the same error when attempting to put a function into the **value** attribute of the **apex:column** element.  That is not allowed, and instead you should put the function into the **value** attribute of the **apex:column**'s *parameter*:

```
<!-- WRONG -->
<apex:column value="{!RIGHT(line.name, 5)}"/>

<!-- RIGHT -->
<apex:column>
  <apex:outputText value="{!RIGHT(line.name, 5)}"/>
</apex:column>
```